# I am getting this error in my python code fr_height, fr_width, _ = frame.shape AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

The error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\KGB\PycharmProjects\Screen_rec\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/KGB/PycharmProjects/Screen_rec/main.py
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KGB\PycharmProjects\Screen_rec\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    fr_height, fr_width, _ = frame.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is given here:

```py
import datetime

from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

import sys

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
file_name = f'{time_stamp}.mp4'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
captured_video = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, width, height))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    img_final = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    _, frame = webcam.read()
    fr_height, fr_width, _ = frame.shape
    img_final[0:fr_height, 0: fr_width, :] = frame[0: fr_height, 0: fr_width, :]
    cv2.imshow('Secret Capture', img_final)

    # cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)

    captured_video.write(img_final)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break
```

I am trying to build a python program that screen records.
I have been looking for many solutions online but none of them I found would work, this program is my first advanced project as a student

Comment: Often means your video capture failed to get a frame

Comment: I found the answer, I just had to change the `webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
` to `webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
`
Hope this helps everyone who has the same and/or 'similar' issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I just had to change the `webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`  to `webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` 
Hope this helps everyone who has the same and/or 'similar' issue